# How to make php foreach counter In this example

Tags: php

Get all the results `$index = 1;`

Why `$index` not added 1 Although I wrote `$index++;` Before closing `foreach`?

```
$index = 1;
foreach ($months as $month) {

if( $index = '1' ){ ?>

   <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="card border-info">
       <a href="vote.php?id=<?php echo $month['id']; ?>"><?php echo $month['month_name']; ?></a>
     </div>
   </div>
<?php }

elseif( $index = '2' || $index = '5' || $index = '8' || $index = '11' ){  ?>
   <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="card border-primary">
       <a href="vote.php?id=<?php echo $month['id']; ?>"><?php echo $month['month_name']; ?></a>
     </div>
   </div>
<?php }

elseif( $index = '3' || $index = '6' || $index = '9' || $index = '12' ){  ?>
   <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="card border-success">
       <a href="vote.php?id=<?php echo $month['id']; ?>"><?php echo $month['month_name']; ?></a>
     </div>
   </div>
<?php }

elseif( $index = 4 || $index = 7 || $index = 10 || $index = 13 ){  ?>
   <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="card border-danger ">
       <a href="vote.php?id=<?php echo $month['id']; ?>"><?php echo $month['month_name']; ?></a>
     </div>
   </div>
<?php }



$index++;
}
```

Comment: You are using assignment operator `=` instead of comparision that is `==`

Comment: This question really should be closed as a typo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $index = '1'

will set 1 to `$index`, you are assigning values instead of checking them. It has to be like

```
if($index == '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem comes from the following line :

```
if( $index = '1' ){ ?>
```

The `=` must be `==` :

```
if( $index == '1' ){ ?>
```

Else you're initializing the `$index` to 1 in every iteration.

Comment: `$index === '1' ` wouldn't this be wrong? because index is integer so === would be wrong since type would mismatch

Comment: True @DanyalSandeelo, Updated..